# Resource Cannot be found error when uploading a file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new in ASP.NET MVC stuff so:

I've done my fair share of searching for a problem similar to this, but I can't find anything that directly relates to my problem.

On one of my Views, there is an upload dialog. Selecting the file works great, but as soon as I press upload, I get an error saying `Resource Cannot be found error` in the browser.

This is the method in my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
        {  
            HttpPostedFileBase File = Request.Files["uploadFile"];
            if (File != null)
            {
                //If this is True, then its Working.,
            }

            if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MarketPlace\\Uploads"),
                                               Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));
                uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

and here is the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "FileUpload", "MarketPlace", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section class="col-sm-6">
                <section class="panel">
                    <header class="panel-heading">
                        <p> Uploads</p>
                    </header>
                    <section class="panel">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Type: </td>
                                <td><bold>@ViewBag.Type</bold></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name: </td>
                                <td><bold>@ViewBag.Name</bold></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" />
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="btnSubmit" />
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </div>
    }
```

Please help me with my error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "MarketPlace", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) ...
```

Now i got it right (copied from a project of mine)

Comment: Oh damn. Thats embarrassing hehe. I've changed it around but it still isn't working, same error

Comment: does it enter the method? put a breakpoint in it to see if it hits it

Comment: maybe a typo in the controllername also

Comment: Nope, still no difference, even though they were all okay

Comment: No its actually the signature... let me correct my answer

Comment: should work now, that is if your controller is named MarketPlaceController

Comment: Second answer is wrong, I use that and everything has squiggly lines underneath in the view :(

Comment: added a closing bracket... is it that?